# In a turbofan, why are there no stators behind the fan?

Tags: turbofan, engine-design

Why are there no stators behind the fan? At least, I've never seen any turbofan design that has stators right behind it. ([Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LaKlE2h3Jw) is the latest turbofan I've looked at, the CFM56. Cutaway part starts around 00:35.)

The purpose of stators is to redirect the airflow to be mostly axial. Without them, the air would be spiralling too much.

The fan is the biggest compressor so I would think stators are needed there more than any other place, but apparently that's wrong. I just do not know why it's wrong.

**Edit:** Yep, there are stators there after all. Just because they're not shown in a video doesn't mean they aren't there. Oh well.

Comment: I'm not sure your premise is correct. AFAIK, turbofans do have stators in the bypass flow. If you go through the cutaway video you link to frame-by-frame, you can see them.

Comment: This video is a bit misleading ([higher resolution video](https://youtu.be/KjYw0GdRpm0?t=151)). At 0:54, by some difficult to understand camera displacement, the booster stators start contra-rotate and the rotors become stationary except the fan. At least, the booster rotors and the fan should be synchronous (N1).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

Right behind the fan you can see the stators.

---

[image]

Here they are from behind.

---

[image]

Here is the fan removed, with the (1) fan stators (outlet guide vanes), and (2) inlet guide vanes for the compressor (booster).

---

Just like I [wrote here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/43302/14897):

> On the funny side, here's a [thumbnail from RR's own YouTube channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2xoZ.png), absolutely bonkers [exhaust](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/37963/14897). Don't trust illustrations.

[image]
(CFM56-5A manual)

---

You can watch the fan removal here: [CFM56 7B Fan Blade Removal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9EJLE9_ELI)

Below is the stator assembly for the **GE90:**

[image]

---

Image sources:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_CFM-56_(3852495197).jpg
- [https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A319-114,*S7*-_Siberia_Airlines_AN1710042.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A319-114,_S7_-_Siberia_Airlines_AN1710042.jpg)
- https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3194/2378036305_e14dab2949_b.jpg
- http://memberfiles.freewebs.com/70/53/41845370/photos/GE90-BUILDUP/Image678.jpg

Comment: Where is the inlet guide vane? I have read it is placed before the rotor of the compressor? Is inlet guide vane and stator after fan you mentioned same?

Comment: @Auberron: Ctrl+F "inlet guide vane", it's in the answer ;-)

Comment: [Picture of OGV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KGsN.jpg) for a GE90. [Source](http://ctlaerospace.com/documents/CTL_R0_Presentation.pdf).